# Why does the my method in different JS objects produce the same results?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm learning Javascript so any help here would be appreciated. In the following code snippet, I created two objects johnTip and markTip that calculate the tip summary of John and Mark. The method tipCalculator is implemented the same way for both objects. However, after calling markTip.calcTip(), I found that tipsJohn would be overriden by tipsMark, i.e, they have the same values. Does anyone know what's wrong behind the scene and how to fix this? Thank you.

I've tried switching the order of calling this method on johnTip and markTip but didn't fix the bug.

The expected results would be that tipsJohn and tipsMark are separate objects (arrays). However, it seems like they have the same values after markTip.calcTip was called.

```js
var johnTip = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  calcTip: function() {
    tips = [];
    finalBills = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
        tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
      } else if (this.bills[i] < 200) {
        tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.15;
      } else {
        tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.1;
      }
      finalBills[i] = tips[i] + this.bills[i];
    }

    return [tips, finalBills];
  }
}

var markTip = {
  bills: [77, 375, 110, 45],
  calcTip: function() {
    tips = [];
    finalBills = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      if (this.bills[i] < 100) {
        tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
      } else if (this.bills[i] < 300) {
        tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.10;
      } else {
        tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.25;
      }
      finalBills[i] = tips[i] + this.bills[i];
    }

    return [tips, finalBills];
  }
}

let [tipsJohn, finalBillsJohn] = johnTip.calcTip();
let [tipsMark, finalBillsMark] = markTip.calcTip();
console.log('Mark\'s tip summary: ' + tipsMark);
console.log('Mark\'s final bills paid: ' + finalBillsMark);
console.log('John\'s tip summary: ' + tipsJohn);
console.log('John\'s final bills paid: ' + finalBillsJohn);
```

Comment: Try and declare your variables properly `const tips = [];` for example, and `const finalBills = [];`.

Comment: where is the problem - tips for Marks and John are different - ?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - that may likely be due to my edit. In order to eliminate the syntax error created by not declaring `tipsJohn, finalBillsJohn, tipsMark, finalBillsMark`. I added `let` in order to declare and define them.

Comment: @RandyCasburn you ruined all the fun ;)

Comment: I didn't say it caused _this_ problem. But if you don't declare your variables properly you'll probably run into problems like this at some point.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I don't think that should impact the OP's problem. The code doesn't seem to have that problem of reusing arrays.

Comment: Thank you guys. This problem vanished when I save tips and finalBills as each object's properties. Interesting. Still don't know what was wrong with the code above.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Interestingly, local variable tips created in object method can be accessed (meaning not undefined) after calling this method. Even though the output is not named tips. For example:  [tipsJohn, finalBillsJohn] = johnTip.calcTip(); tips === tipsJohn -> true. Does anyone know why this is the case in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a variable without decaling it it has global scope.

```
x = 5;
```

Makes a global variable.

```
let x = 5;
```

Creates a variable that only has scope to the current block.

Change both of your arrays to

```
let tips = [];

let finalBills = [];
```

And they will be different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `var finalBills;` outside declaration of markTip and johnTip.
You need to store them in different `var`.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, since it reassigns the variables each time you call the methods, it doesn't reuse the old array.